# Java advanced imaging not available to EJB modules in Glassfish on Mac, but show up in EARs

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, classpath, jai, jboss-weld

I'm developing an application that uses the Geotools, which in turn uses the Java Advanced imaging (JAI) API to run under Glassfish. When I run my application from Netbeans as an EJB jar file it fails to deploy because of a ClassNotFoundException during CDI scanning :

```
com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class org.autogena.skyserver.data.filetypes.SwathFile
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:218)
    ....
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class org.autogena.skyserver.data.filetypes.SwathFile
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:189)
    .....
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/jai/PropertySource
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    ....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.PropertySource
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

However, if I package the EJB module into an EAR file then I don't get the exception above and it seems to load ok.

Since on the Mac the JAI core classes are in the system extension library I'm baffled how it's not showing up on the classpath.

Is there a difference between an EJB jar and and EAR file when it comes to class loading, or is this a big in Glassfish / Weld?

Come to think of it - how is glassfish finding the libraries my prject uses anyway - they don't seem to be packaged into the ejb jar file - is netbeans doing something clever under the hood here that's going somehow askew?

thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the CLASSPATH on Glassfish in order to use the JAI libraries.